# Java Midlet Deployment

Tags: java, java-me, midp, midlet, ota

So, I've develop a simple hello world midlet using the Samsung SDK 1.1.2 and I've Packaged the midlet. Now I have two files (a JAR/JAD) combination. How do I get these installed on my phone?

As you can tell from the question, I'm new to phone development. Trying to deploy to a Samsung handset on ATT.

I'm trying to test out the entire development cycle - the emulators work great for writing code but I really need to make sure the Midlet works as expected on the target phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest you read up a little on [OTA delivery](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/ota/) of applications, for background.

You have a number of options for deployment, here's a few.

- Connect your handset to a computer via bluetooth, cable, or wifi and copy the JAR file over.
  I'm not sure if Samsung support this, but other handset manufacturers certainly provide 'manager' software you can download and install on a computer to do this.  If your app relies on user data in the JAD this may not be an idea option, or you could include default data in the JAR.
- Place your JAD and JAR file on a web server you have access to, from which they can be downloaded to your phone.  You'll need to ensure that the MIME types for the JAD and JAR files are set correctly, they may not be by default.  Exactly how you do this depends on your server - here's an [example](http://www.summet.com/blog/2007/11/04/mime-types-for-hosting-j2me-jar-and-jad-files/) method.  (Presumably you have a web/data access service from AT&T.)  If all is well you can fetch the JAD file from the phone's browser and the handset will then prompt you to confirm you wish to proceed and download the full JAR and install.  Mobile Network Operators have a variable attitude to supporting JAD and JAR access, for example you may find you have to run your server on port 80 or 8080 for it to work in some cases.
- Join a service that will host an application for you.  One I'm aware of is [GetJar](http://my.getjar.com/site/Developers).  I'm not sure of the details, but doing this will mean you don't have to run your own web server.

Apart from basic deployment you might consider [signing](http://www.spindriftpages.net/blog/dave/2006/06/18/midlet-jar-signing-a-tutorial-revised/) your application - a process that basically allows you to assert your 'true' identity to a handset.  The advantage of doing this is that signed applications can present fewer network access confirmation dialogs and the like to the handset owner.  Also, when the application is being deployed, the user will see a message about unsignedness that might include the word 'untrusted' or similar, and that can be off-putting.  (Having said that, some major applications out there have been unsigned.)

Hope that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly copy the jar/jad over via usb or bluetooth, but the Samsung devices I've used will not install a file that's been manually copied over.

Unfortunately the other methods are significantly more work.